# How to interpret "on the event" in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

I have come across several works that use "on the event" to relate a proposition involving random variables to an event, but I am confused about the precise meaning of it. For example, I am struggling to interpret (C1) in Theorem 1 from [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/jeeff.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epemantle/papers/jeeff.pdf) (copied below). In this case, $\mathbf{E}(X_{n+1}-X_n \mid \mathcal{F}) \leq -a$ and $\{X_n > J \}$ are the proposition and event of interest respectively.

> Let $X_n$ be random variables and suppose that there exist constants $a > 0, J, V < \infty$, and $p > 2$, such that $X_0 \leq J$, and for all $n$,
> $$ \mathbf{E}(X_{n+1} - X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n ) \leq -a \text{ on the event } \{ X_n > J \} \quad \text{(C1)}$$
> and
> $$ \mathbf{E}(|X_{n+1}-X_n|^p \mid X_0,\ldots,X_n) \leq V \quad \text{(C2)}$$
> Then for any $r \in (0,p-1)$ there is a $c=c(p,a,V,J,r)>0$ such that $\mathbf{E}(X_n^+)^r < c$ for all $n$.

Note that $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ is the filtration to which $\{X_n\}$ is adapted to.

I have two ideas about the exact meaning of (C1). For both interpretations, let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the probability space, and define $A_n:= \{ \omega \in \Omega : \mathbf{E}(X_{n+1} - X_n \mid \mathcal{F_n})(\omega) \leq -a \}\in \mathcal{F}$, and $B_n := \{ \omega \in \Omega : X_n(\omega) > J \} \in \mathcal{F}$.

1. The first idea is to interpret (C1) from an *almost surely*, conditional probability perspective as
   $$ P( A_n | B_n ) = 1.$$
   However, this definition runs into problems when $B_n = \emptyset$.
2. The second idea is to interpret (C1) from the perspective of subsets of the sample space as
   $$ B_n \subseteq A_n , $$
   which should be the same as $\forall \omega \in B_n: \mathbf{E}(X_{n+1} - X_n \mid \mathcal{F_n})(\omega) \leq -a$.

Are one of these interpretations the correct way to view (C1), or have I completely missed the mark here and the meaning is something different? More generally, what is the correct way to interpret "on the event"? I have seen similar statements show up in other works, relating a proposition involving random variables to an event. Sometimes they used "conditioned on the event" instead, or even "on the set".

Comment: To say that a random object $T$ satisfies some property $P$ "on the event" $E$ typically means that if $\omega \in E$ then $T(\omega)$ satisfies $P.$ For example, you can have a random variable $X$ which is $\mathsf{Norm}(0;1)$ and define $Y  = \dfrac{1}{X}$ "on the event" $X \neq 0$ and $Y = 0$ "on the event" $X = 0.$ Further, you could also say "on the event" $X > 0,$ we have $Y > 0$ as well, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be overthinking what "on the event" means.
You can interpret it as follows: if $\omega \in \{X_n > J\}$, then $\mathbb{E} (X_{n+1} - X_n \, | \, \mathcal{F}_n)(\omega) \leq -a$.